# DataTables multi search is truncating a single result

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have a fairly large amount of data that I am trying to filter for exact matches by a single column using a checkbox. I am having a difficult time creating a multi-search and returning **ALL** results. For example if I search for CHPU3P0100BKEW_DE, CHPU3P0100BKEW_FR, CHPU3P0100BKEW_IT and toggle the exact match checkbox, my data table will only display the rows of CHPU3P0100BKEW_FR and CHPU3P0100BKEW_IT. Furthermore, if I search for a single result such as CHPU3P0100BKEW_IT **or** CHPU3P0100BKEW, there are 0 rows as as result. It seems like it is always truncating exactly one search result. My code looks like:

```
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
        var search = '^\\s' + searchOptions["multiSearchValue"].trim() + '\\s*$';
        if (this.checked) {
            oTable
                .api()
                .column(0)
                .search(search, true, false)
            .draw();
        }
        else {
            oTable
                .api()
                .search('')
                .columns()
                .search('')
            .draw();
        }
    });
```

I originally thought that this may have to do with regex, but I have tried it both with and without regex and it no longer seems that may be the culprit so I am not sure what is going on.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `searchOptions["multiSearchValue"]` populated? If you want to search exactly for `AAA` or `BBB` or `CCC`, I would expect your regex string to be `^(AAA|BBB|CCC)$`. If that does not help, can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for responding. searchOptions["multiSearchValue"] is a string like: "CHPU3P0100BKEW|CHPU3P0100BKEW_DE|CHPU3P0100BKEW_ES" that worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @andrewjames this is resolved. Changing the value of search to

`var search = '^(' + searchOptions["multiSearchValue"].trim() + ')$';`
worked perfectly